# Answer is always 0

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

class empl
{

    int p, n, r, i;

    void accept()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter Principal amount");
            int p = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter no of years");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter rate");
            int r = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("" + e);
        }
    }

    int calculate()
    {
        i = (p * n * r) / 100;
        return (i);
    }
}

class bank
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        empl e = new empl();
        e.accept();
        int a = e.calculate();
        System.out.println("i=" + a);
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in java.The above program always gives me result as 0.I have also tried many different input values but the result remains the same.I am sure that that there is no problem in formula.Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Integer division is back. Consider formatting your code properly. It gives pain in eyes to read it.

Comment: You should really get used to indent your code ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style ), because in the current form it's really hard for you and for other people to get a good overview.

Comment: Dude !! Keep the title as it is. :)

Comment: You are doing integer by integer division. It seems you want it to be a double. Use `return (p*n*r)/100.0`

Comment: I have edited his code

Comment: Sonce you are writing an interactive program, consider using the `Console` class. Since you are doing financial work, consider using the `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` class with the appropriate scale; then, you have control over rounding.  Learn about *banker's rounding*, and then watch *Office Space* for an example of rounding follies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `accept` method declares new *local* variables for `p`, `n` and `r` - it doesn't assign values to the *instance* variables, which will still have a value of 0. Rather than declaring local variables, you should just assign values to the instance variables. So for example, this line:

```
int p = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

should be:

```
p = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Additionally, there's the fact that the arithmetic is entirely performed in integer maths, as others have pointed out. That doesn't matter if you *really* want an integer result (e.g. if you don't mind getting 0 as a result when `p`, `n` and `r` are all 10) - but if you want to be able to get non-integer results, you probably want something like:

```
double calculate() {
    return (p * n * r) / 100.0; 
}
```

... or perhaps use `BigDecimal` instead, if the exact digit values are important to you. (`double` is appropriate for natural quantities such as height and weight; `BigDecimal` is appropriate for financial calculations. Search for questions on `double` and `BigDecimal` for more information about this.)

Comment: indeed - I jumped too quick to the question. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
int p=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
int r=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

p, n, r are instance variables. You dont have to declare `int p` again. Just use `p=...`

Answer (score 2):

If the product `p*n*r` is less than `100`, dividing it by `100` will truncate to `0`, since you cast it as an `int`. Change this to a `double` and divide by `100.0` instead.

```
int calculate(){
    return (p * n * r) / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, with the code as written, if the user enters 100, 100 and 100 it will *still* return 0. We don't actually know that the OP needs floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are calculating using integers.

```
i=(p*n*r)/100;
```

That line will multiply `p`, `n` and `r`, divide it by 100 and then throw away the stuff after the decimal point, yielding 0 unless `p*n*r` exceeds 100.

The solution here is to use some other data type, such as `double` or `BigDecimal` depending on what error tolerance you have.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the calculate method,

```
double calculate() {
    return ((double)(p*n*r)/(double)100;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly cast two sides, one is enough. The other will be implicitly cast.